# Defining my very own copy constructor

Tags: c++

I was writing this program where I defined a `class X` and manually defined its constructors and destructor so that I could have a print statement in each of them and see when they are called.

However, the problem seems to be with my definition of the copy constructor.

It gives the following error:

> warning: passing `const X` as `this` argument of `int X::getI()` discards `const`

What's the cause of this error?

Code snippet of class:

```
class X {
    public:
        X() {
            cout << "Default Constructor called\n";
            i = 0;
        }
        X(int i) {
            cout << "Parameterized Constructor called\n";
            this->i = i;
        }
        X(const X& x) {
            cout << "Copy Constructor called\n";
            i = x.getI();
        }
        ~X() {
            cout << "Destructor called\n";
        }
        int getI() {
            return i;
        }
    private:
        int i;
};
```

Comment: It compiles without error if I remove the const from the argument of the copy constructor.

Comment: The argument to the copy constructor should really be `const`.  The problem is that `getI` is not.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Ok, but why should a copy constructor have const?

Comment: Because otherwise, `const X original; X copy = original;` cannot compile.  Semantically, making a copy of something is not supposed to modify what is being copied and the way to express this in C++ is to declare it `const`.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to call the non-`const` member function `getI` through a `const` reference.  This is not allowed.  Since `getI` doesn't modify `this` object, it should be declared as `const`.

```
int
getI() const
{
  return this->i;
}
```

Then you'll be able to call it even through a `const` reference.

Comment: So, can const references or objects only call const functions?

Comment: Yes, because calling through a `const` reference passes a `const` `this` pointer and while converting a non-`const` pointer to a `const` pointer is an implicit conversion, the opposite direction is not allowed (unless you use a really ugly `const_cast`).  If you think about it, it makes sense: You can always make an *additional* promise not to modify something but you can never step back from a promise you have already made.

Answer (score 1):

`getI()` not a `const` member function. You are not allowed to call it on objects that are `const`. In the copy constructor, `x` is a `const` object. Hence, you can't call

```
x.getI();
```

Change `getI()` to a `const` member function.

```
    int getI() const {
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace::std;


class X {
    public:
        X() {
            cout << "Default Constructor called\n";
            i = 0;
        }


        X(int i) {
            cout << "Parameterized Constructor called\n";
            this->i = i;
        }
        X(const X& x) {
            cout << "Copy Constructor called\n";
            i = x.getI();
        }
        ~X() {
            cout << "Destructor called\n";
        }
        int getI() const {
            return i;
        }
    private:
        int i;
};

int main()
{
}
```

Here is the correct code, u have to make getI as const